# Adding a double border to a linear-gradient-filled-div colors the border too

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

I have a div that I want to be gradient filled.  I also want to add a double border to the div but I do NOT want it to have the color gradient of the div.

I have my code here to show the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/753rxozh/1/

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px double black;
  /* box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px black; */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, orange);
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

I tried messing around with box-shadow, but couldn't figure out how to make that a double border.

With the code above this is what I get:

[image]

I would like to get the border to not have that "reversed color" or any color at all.  Between the 2 borders should just be white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate box-shadow property... you can have more than one!

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, orange);
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 0 0 2px black,
    inset 0 0 0 8px white,
    inset 0 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outline with a black border and box shadow

```css
.colors {
    outline: 3px solid white;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px black;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: linear-gradient( #fff, orange);
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply adjust the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) of the gradient and you can keep the transparency:

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 10px double black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, orange) padding-box;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```

Another idea is to consider `outline-offset` and you can still keep the transparency:

```css
.colors {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  outline:2px solid black;
  outline-offset:4px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin:10px;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, orange) padding-box;
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors"></div>
```